# Asp.net MVC Index page without domain paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, path

I believe this should have been asked and answered somewhere already, or is just a very basic thing, but I did not manage to find anything at all, I am guessing I might be querying my search wrong.

Either way, what I want is to display Index page without any domain paths.

What I want:

http://localhost:50024/

How I was able to make it with domain paths:

http://localhost:50024/Home/Index

I made a HomeController.cs and added a GET method for the Index view... which is in the Home folder under Views folder, and of course that creates domain paths. I do not care if I have to make extra controller or something, I just want it to display my index page without any paths. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your `route` and your method for index view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set default values for the parameters in the route configuration in global.asax, similar to this:

```
routes.MapRoute( "Default", // Route name  
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters  
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults );
```

So that when the route parameters are missing, the routing system points the request to the desired controller and action.

Comment: Right.. I actually saw this one before, but always thought it was used for something else... my bad. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: That would be in `route.config` rather than `Global.asax`

Comment: @StuartL In my MVC 4 projects that code is in Global.asax.cs under RegisterRoutes method.

Comment: Same here, it is in Global.asax.cs under RegisterRoutes method. Thanks again Mihai!

Answer (score 0):

just tested myself so i know it works

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "" })">Test</a>
```

obviously replace with what you have for the defaults in your routing if you have modified them or something

Answer (score 0):

If all you're after is the "root" URL, you can also use `~/`, like so:

```
<a href="~/">Home</a>
```

The Razor engine is smart enough to parse that URL in place, without needing to use the UrlHelper class.

Comment: I did not have a "root URL" to begin with, it was always /{ViewFolderName}/{ViewName}, so link which returns me to "root" URL was giving me 404. :) Mihai's answer is exactly what I was looking for.